# ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que el for no repita el mensaje exitoso?

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, bucle-for

Estoy queriendo ingresar varios datos a mysql con bucle **for**, pero lo que no quiero es que se repita muchas veces el mensaje: **"SE AGREGÓ"**. solo quiero que salga una sola vez.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
El código, los errores y demás datos van como texto, así es más fácil replicar tu problema; nadie te va a responder con imágenes. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: Lectura sugerida: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.

Comment: sin entender absolutamente nada de tu codigo,vos estas contestando tu propia pregunta.. si queres que salga una sola vez, sacalo del for...

Comment: Hola pablo como te comento @Alfabravo debes editar tu pregunta, tu duda es facil de responder, pero como no se ve nisiquiera bien la imagen no se puede ayudar

Answer (score 1):

Te paso unos cambios al codigo para lograr lo que comentas que queres hacer

```
//antes del for
$bien = 0;

//dentro del for
if($consulta){
  $bien++;
}

//despues del for
if($bien == $contador){
  echo "Se agregaron todos bien";
}else{
  echo "Fallaron ".($contador-$bien)." de $bien totales";
}
```